# HTTP request fails when executed asynchronously

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a tiny application in Go that can send an HTTP request to all IP addresses in hopes to find a specific content. The issue is that the application seems to crash in a very peculiar way when the call is executed asynchronously.

ip/validator.go

```
package ip

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "time"
)

type ipValidator struct {
    httpClient http.Client
    path       string
    exp        *regexp.Regexp
    confirmationChannel *chan string
}

func (this *ipValidator) validateUrl(url string) bool {
    response, err := this.httpClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return false
    }

    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    result := this.exp.Match(bodyBytes)

    if result && this.confirmationChannel != nil {
        *this.confirmationChannel <- url
    }
    return result
}

func (this *ipValidator) ValidateIp(addr ip) bool {
    httpResult := this.validateUrl("http://" + addr.ToString() + this.path)
    httpsResult := this.validateUrl("https://" + addr.ToString() + this.path)

    return httpResult || httpsResult
}

func (this *ipValidator) GetSuccessChannel() *chan string {
    return this.confirmationChannel
}

func NewIpValidadtor(path string, exp *regexp.Regexp) ipValidator {
    return newValidator(path, exp, nil)
}

func NewAsyncIpValidator(path string, exp *regexp.Regexp) ipValidator {
    c := make(chan string)
    return newValidator(path, exp, &c)
}

func newValidator(path string, exp *regexp.Regexp, c *chan string) ipValidator {
    httpClient := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 2,
    }
    return ipValidator{httpClient, path, exp, c}
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "./ip"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func processOutput(c *chan string) {
    for true {
        url := <- *c
        fmt.Println(url)
    }
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    fmt.Printf("path: %s regex: %s", args[0], args[1])

    regexp, regexpError := regexp.Compile(args[1])
    if regexpError != nil {
        fmt.Println("The provided regexp is not valid")
        return
    }
    currentIp, _ := ip.NewIp("172.217.22.174")
    validator := ip.NewAsyncIpValidator(args[0], regexp)
    successChannel := validator.GetSuccessChannel()

    go processOutput(successChannel)

    for currentIp.HasMore() {
        go validator.ValidateIp(currentIp)
        currentIp = currentIp.Increment()
    }
}
```

Note the line that says `go validator.ValidateIp(currentIp)` in main.go. Should I remove the word "go" to execute everything within the main routine, the code works as expected -> it sends requests to IP addresses starting 172.217.22.174 and should one of them return a legitimate result that matches the regexp that the ipValidator was initialized with, the URL is passed to the channel and the value is printed out by `processOutput` function from main.go. The issue is that simply adding `go` in front of `validator.ValidateIp(currentIp)` breaks that functionality. In fact, according to the debugger, I never seem to go past the line that says `response, err := this.httpClient.Get(url)` in validator.go.

The struggle is real. Should I decide to scan the whole internet, there's 256^4 IP addresses to go through. It will take years, unless I find a way to split the process into multiple routines.

Comment: "the application seems to crash in a very peculiar way" -- What way? Show your error/stack trace, please.

Comment: the application is not waiting for a response after calling `ValidateIp`, Your `httpClient`, waits 2 seconds for response, during this time, your main thread completes execution and exits.

Comment: I assume that there is no crash. The application just exits. That's to be expected, since you are not waiting for the goroutines to finish. main just returns, terminating the program. Aside from that, you should disable keep-alive in the HTTP client, and  pointers to channels are, erm, pointless (just use `chan string`).

Comment: @Flimzy if you read the whole thread, you would know it. There is no stack trace. The routine just never ends

Comment: @whitespace unfortunately this is not the case at the moment. Obviously this will happen, but for the time being the main thread takes many hours to finish. Only the itaration through such a large number of IPs takes a lot of time. I haven't seen the application actually end yet and yet I have seen the application not hitting the break point when executed in a separate routine

Comment: @Peter no the application doesn't end. the main thread has enough work for the next few hours

Comment: @KamilJanowski It sounds like the program is blocked. To find where it's blocked, dump the goroutine stack traces by sending the process a SIGQUIT.

Comment: You should add various logging lines to your code to track down how your code is run. There is no point guessing blindly what went wrong. I guess your fan-out is blocked somewhere so it is not actually fanning out the works.

Comment: I know what line gets stuck and I described it, but I cannot debug the internal go libraries to figure out what got stuck over there